# compiling android SDL from libsdl.org ant install fails with BUILD FAILED

Tags: android, ant, installation, sdl

Help! I've been trying to compile & test the recent SDL (1.3) port from libsdl.org

(found here: http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/android-project.zip)

### steps

cd android-project
ndk-build
ant install
sh data.sh

It wouldn't compiled using NDK-r5b, kept complaining that "SDL.h" not found ... even though the paths, etc seemed to be setup properly.

So I installed r4b and then cd into the (fresh) android-project directory and ran ndk-build ... with no errors. (also checked to be sure it was using r4b using "which ndk-build" first)

IT BUILDS OK ... but the "ant install" step fails.

> sgtwhy@sgtwhy-PC
>   /cygdrive/t/Android/android-project $
>   adb devices List of devices attached
>   emulator-5554   device
>
> sgtwhy@sgtwhy-PC
>   /cygdrive/t/Android/android-project $
>   ant install Buildfile:
>   T:\Android\android-project\build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   T:\Android\android-project\build.xml:49:
>   taskdef class
>   com.android.ant.SetupTask  cannot be
>   found  using the classloader
>   AntClassLoader[]
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

I'm using the "stock" build.xml file and verified the *.properties files appear to have correct paths as well.

Any ideas how to get this working ? Now that its compiled - need to push it to the phone somehow.

[EDIT / UPDATE ]

This helped! 
http://arithmetic-game.googlecode.com/hg/Arithgame-android/readme.txt?r=d05a65aa7d91e482398298b8bc8871ad917c9ad1

I went into the project and ran android.bat to update the properties files.

$ cd android-project
$ android.bat update project -t 3 --path .

and then ran "ant install" - with success!

> sgtwhy@sgtwhy-PC
>   /cygdrive/t/Android/android-project $
>   ant install Buildfile:
>   T:\Android\android-project\build.xml
>       [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 10
>       [setup] Project Target: Android 1.6
>       [setup] API level: 4
>       [setup]
>       [setup] ------------------
>       [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
>       [setup] No library dependencies.
>       [setup]
>       [setup] ------------------
>       [setup]
>       [setup] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on
>   all  Android versions.
>       [setup]
>       [setup] Importing rules file: tools\ant\main_rules.xml
>
> -debug-obfuscation-check:
>
> -set-debug-mode:
>
> -compile-tested-if-test:
>
> -pre-build:
>
> -dirs:
>        [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>       [mkdir] Created dir: T:\Android\android-project\bin
>       [mkdir] Created dir: T:\Android\android-project\gen
>       [mkdir] Created dir: T:\Android\android-project\bin\classes
>
> -aidl:
>        [echo] Compiling aidl files into Java classes...
>
> -renderscript:
>        [echo] Compiling RenderScript files into Java classes and
>   RenderScript byte code...
>
> -resource-src:
>        [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...
>
> -pre-compile:
>
> compile:
>       [javac] T:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:384:
>   warning: 'inclu deantruntime' was not
>   set, defaulting to
>   build.sysclasspath=last; set to false
>   f or repeatable builds
>       [javac] Compiling 2 source files to
>   T:\Android\android-project\bin\classes
>
> -post-compile:
>
> -obfuscate:
>
> -dex:
>        [echo] Converting compiled files and external libraries into
>   T:\Android\and
>   roid-project\bin\classes.dex...
>
> -package-resources:
>        [echo] Packaging resources
>        [aapt] Creating full resource package...
>
> -package-debug-sign: [apkbuilder] Creating SDLApp-debug-unaligned.apk
>   and signing it with a debug key ...
>
> debug:
>        [echo] Running zip align on final apk...
>        [echo] Debug Package: T:\Android\android-project\bin\SDLApp-debug.apk
>
> install:
>        [echo] Installing T:\Android\android-project\bin\SDLApp-debug.apk
>   onto defa ult emulator or device...
>        [exec]     pkg: /data/local/tmp/SDLApp-debug.apk
>        [exec] Success
>        [exec] 267 KB/s (946557 bytes in 3.455s)
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 19
>   seconds